# Why speed of light is constant with respect to any inertial frame of reference?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, inertial-frames

Its getting too difficult to think.if we travel at the speed of light then will light will cross us at same speed or travel with us adjacent (special theory of relativity)

Answer (score 0):

The constant speed of light is confirmed by the Michelson-Morrey experiment . 
But I don't know why it is constant. 
It's a measured quantity, just as G is.

Comment: No this experiment doesn't prove that

Comment: @user117953 Does it not prove the frame independence of the speed of light?

Comment: How please explain?